# how set time for leave page event

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

i saw a nice mobile app design and really curious how i can run this effect in reality. let me explain with picture...

[take look please](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6HadK.jpg)

so, when page is loading, they close. and when we want to leave and visit the next page, first, they'll hide and then they'll shows again and like this...

---

Edited!
The question is, **how can i set time for leave event**, i could show the loading style but when i want to visit the next page, it will be very fast, or if i understood right, the effect doesn't shows..

---

my Main.js

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("div.top").addClass(" show");
    $("div.bottom").addClass(" show");
}); 

$(window).bind('beforeunload', function () {
    setTimeout(function () {
        $("div.top").removeClass(" show");
        $("div.bottom").removeClass(" show");
        $("div.top").addClass(" fade");
        $("div.bottom").addClass(" fade");
    }, 2000);
});
```

my content

```
<div class="loading">
    <div class="top">
        <h1>Logo</h1>
        <h3>Page one</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="bottom">

        <br>
        <a href="2.html">Next</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

My StyleSheet

```
.loading {
    position: relative;
    text-align: center;
    color: black;
}

.loading .top {
    background-color: white;
    position: fixed;
    min-width: 100%;
    min-height: 50vh;
    max-height: 50vh;
    top: -50vh;
    -webkit-transition: top ease .1s;
    transition: top ease .1s;
    box-shadow: 0px 2px 5px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.23);
    z-index: 100;
}
.loading .bottom {
    background-color: #fedd30;
    background-image: url(bg-pattern.png);
    background-repeat: repeat-x;
    position: fixed;
    min-width: 100%;
    min-height: 50vh;
    max-height: 50vh;
    bottom: -50vh;
    -webkit-transition: bottom ease .1s;
    transition: bottom ease .1s;
}
.loading .top.fade {
    top: -500px;
    -webkit-transition: top ease .9s;
    transition: top ease .9s;
}
.loading .top.show {
    top: 0px;
    -webkit-transition: top ease .9s;
    transition: top ease .9s;
}
.loading .bottom.fade {
    bottom: -500px;
    -webkit-transition: bottom ease .9s;
    transition: bottom ease .9s;
}
.loading .bottom.show {
    bottom: 0px;
    -webkit-transition: bottom ease .9s;
    transition: bottom ease .9s;
}
```

Comment: And what is your question? please explain it in the question not on title.

Comment: @MahmoodKohansal , sry... edited.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

However I didn't get the meaning of your question completely but if you want the reverse animation of loading, something like [this](https://jsfiddle.net/cvujjdgv/), you must use

```
event.preventDefault();
```

And you can change the time of animation by increase transition time.

If you want to redirect user to a new page after the animation, you can use below code :

```
window.location.href = "http://stackoverflow.com";
```

Comment: Yes, that was what i want... thanks. but, i want this effect display for all pages in document is ready and leave event